# Connection Access Denied for user www-data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple PHP page that connects to a database to read values and this all appears to work fine when I have it deployed locally. However when I deploy to my server then it wont connect - it looks to me like it is ignoring my connection file and using default values...?

```
    <?php
//Database details
include "Connection.php";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
?>

//Contents of Connection.php
<?php
  $user_name = "sam";
$password = "123456";
$database = "clubleague";
$server = "localhost";
?>
```

Error I get back is:

> Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I would have expected it to say Access denied for user "sam", not www-data?
In phpMyAdmin I have a user called Sam attached to the database and I have tried giving it full permissions against Global and the local database but no joy. Any tips, suggestions to get it to connect with my credentials?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Make sure your credentials are ok..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your "Connection.php" isn't included. For avoid this, check the path to file and use "require" instead "include" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). "require" throws you an error in this case and you don't missed them.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_connect` seems to be passed empty `$server`, `$user_name` and `$password`.

By default it connects to the local server through default UNIX socket using credentials the PHP interpreter is running under (which in your case are Apache credentials).

Most probably it's reflected in the web server logs ("Undefined variable: server in ...") and similar.

Please check that `Connection.php` does exist and actually gets included.

Comment: OK for some reason unknown to me right now, the password I was using contained special characters. When I changed the password to "1234" then it worked. The password was only temporary but was baffling nonetheless.